# Spawn multiple images in grid evenly

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have 40 objects placed in 5x8 grid style. The object's image is 50x50. The code that i use for spawning is the following:

```
local spawnImage=function(x,y)
    circle[bCircle] = display.newImage( "dot1.png" )
    circle[bCircle].x =-5+x*55
    circle[bCircle].y = 60+y*55
    sceneGroup:insert(circle[bCircle])
    circle[bCircle].value = bCircle 
    circle[bCircle].tag=false
    numCircle[bCircle]= display.newText(  circle[bCircle].value, spX+x*55, spY+y*55, "Helsinki", 16 )
    circle[bCircle]:addEventListener( "touch", touchi )
    bCircle = bCircle + 1
end

    for y=1,8 do
       for x=1,5 do
         spawnImage(x,y)
       end
     end
```

The thing is that i cant place them evenly in different devices(Simulator)

ipad 
[image: ipad screenshot]

iphone 6
[image: iphone 6]

iphone 5
[image]

Any help? How can i place the objects evenly in different devices? Any ideas? Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't take the display resolution into consideration which is most likely different for all devices. As you're using fixed offsets and sizes you get different results.

Corona can handle the scaling for you if you define the content properties for your project.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the beginning of your code and then use _W and _H as screen width and height:

```
_W= display.contentCenterX
_H= display.contentCenterY
```

so your code will be:

```
    _W= display.contentCenterX
    _H= display.contentCenterY

local spawnImage=function(x,y)
    circle[bCircle] = display.newImage( "dot1.png" )
    circle[bCircle].x = x* (1/5)*_W
    circle[bCircle].y = y* (1/8)*_H
    sceneGroup:insert(circle[bCircle])
    circle[bCircle].value = bCircle 
    circle[bCircle].tag=false
    numCircle[bCircle]= display.newText(  circle[bCircle].value, spX+x*55, spY+y*55, "Helsinki", 16 )
    circle[bCircle]:addEventListener( "touch", touchi )
    bCircle = bCircle + 1
end

    for y=1,8 do
       for x=1,5 do
         spawnImage(x,y)
       end
     end
```